# Using CtkSwitch to change command sent

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I have a working Customtkinter GUI.
In it I have an entry box that you can put an IP address in then a button to ping what is in that entry box.  What I would like is to have the select option to amend the ping command from being a single ping to a constant one.
The working code is below:

```
import customtkinter
import os

customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Dark")  # Modes: "System" (standard), "Dark", "Light"
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")  # Themes: "blue" (standard), "green", "dark-blue"


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # configure window
        self.title("STEVE's IRT TOOL")
        self.geometry(f"{1100}x{580}")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.iconbitmap('icon.ico')

        # configure grid layout (4x4)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure((2, 3), weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)

        def read_output(fp):
            line = fp.readline()
            if line:
                print_out.insert("end", line)
                print_out.see("end")
                print_out.after(10, read_output, fp)

        def switch_event():
            global CHOICE
            if switch_var.get() == "on":
                CHOICE = '-t'
            else :
                CHOICE = '-r'


        def button_ping():
            hostname = info.get()
            fp = os.popen(f"ping {hostname}")
            read_output(fp)

        #def button_ping():
        #    hostname = info.get()
        #    fp = os.popen(f'ping' + " " + CHOICE + " " + hostname)
        #    read_output(fp)

        # create sidebar frame with widgets
        self.sidebar_frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, width=140, corner_radius=0)
        self.sidebar_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4, sticky="nsew")
        self.sidebar_frame.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.logo_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sidebar_frame, text="IRT Tool", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=20, weight="bold"))
        self.logo_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))
        info = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.sidebar_frame, placeholder_text="Enter Input")
        info.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
        sidebar_button_ping = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.sidebar_frame, text="Ping", fg_color="transparent", border_width=2, text_color=("gray10", "#DCE4EE"), command=button_ping)
        sidebar_button_ping.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
        switch_var = customtkinter.StringVar(value="off")
        switch = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(self.sidebar_frame, text="Constant", command=switch_event, variable=switch_var, onvalue="on", offvalue="off")
        switch.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.appearance_mode_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.sidebar_frame, text="Appearance Mode:", anchor="w")
        self.appearance_mode_label.grid(row=9, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 0))
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(self.sidebar_frame, values=["Light", "Dark", "System"],
                                                                       command=self.change_appearance_mode_event)
        self.appearance_mode_optionemenu.grid(row=10, column=0, padx=20, pady=(10, 10))

        # OUTPUT WINDOW
        print_out = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(self, width=250)
        print_out.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=1, padx=(20, 0), pady=(20, 0), sticky="nsew")



    def change_appearance_mode_event(self, new_appearance_mode: str):
        customtkinter.set_appearance_mode(new_appearance_mode)

    def sidebar_button_event(self):
        print("sidebar_button click")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

What I want to have is when the switch is in the off (default state) the command sent is:

```
fp = os.popen(f"ping {hostname}")
```

If the switch is selected it changes to:

```
fp = os.popen(f"ping -t {hostname}")
```

S

Comment: You have code to do exactly what you're asking in your code already, just commented out.  What went wrong with that code?

Comment: If I bring that code into play then the ping function completely fails with:

    fp = os.popen(f'ping' + " " + CHOICE + " " + hostname)
NameError: name 'CHOICE' is not defined

Comment: Get rid of `switch_event()` (you don't really need to do anything immediately in response to the choice being changed), and set `CHOICE` inside `button_ping()`.

Comment: Could I maybe get rid of choice altogether and have two different fp = commands?

I'm getting a bit lost.  haha

Comment: Simply set `onvalue="-t"` and `offvalue=""` in `CTkSwitch(...)` and use command `f"ping {switch_var.get()} {hostname}"`.  However, how can you stop the process then?

Comment: I'll work on that after ;)